# Not able to update a static field from java to mongo db

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

When I try to insert record into Mongo DB from java I am not able to update the static field.

```
  Class1

public class User{

 private String userName;
  private String id;
 private static List<Address> addresses;
  public static List<Address> getAddresses() {
    return addresses;
 }

public static void setAddresses(List<Addresses> addresses) {
    Class1.addresses = addresses;
}

 //getter and setters

 } 

 Class2

 public class Address{

  private String street,
 private String city
 }

  Update.java

User user = new User();
List<Address> add = new ArrayList<Address>();
add.setStreet("CrossWave Street");
add.setCity("Lucia");
user.setUserName("Roy");
user.setId("100");
 User .setAddresses(add);
db.save(user,Class1.class)
```

After this process I am not able to see the address field in the database. I know some issue is there with static field but i am confused

Answer (score 2):

Static fields are at class level. MongoDB documents only work with object level fields. Why do you need to use static fields?

Comment: I am getting another exception when using object field so trying with static.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519014/org-springframework-data-mapping-model-mappinginstantiationexception-with-mongo

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you cannot save static fields along you object as they do not belong to any instance of that class.

Comment: Any example u can give other that the link.

Comment: Did you try to save an object without static field?

Comment: Why would you want to use a `static List<Address>` in the first place instead of `List<Address>` or `Address` ?

Comment: Have other problem while unwinding so tried with static. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519014/org-springframework-data-mapping-model-mappinginstantiationexception-with-mongo